# JavaScript Close on click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that this topic is already talked about but each problem is unique in some way. I tried other fixes and examples on how to make the submenu close when clicking outside of it but without success.

How can I make the uslugi > block_menu close when clicking outside of the box? (not toggling the link)

Currently, the nav item opens on click and closes when clicking on it. See code snippet:

```js
$(".uslugi").click(function() {
  $(this).children().children().toggle();
});
$(".uslugi").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(300, function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
$(".uslugi").on('blur', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Pompadur;
  src: url(fonts/Times New Roman Cyr Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: COPRGTB;
  src: url(fonts/COPRGTB.ttf);
}

#main {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#active {
  width: 50px;
}

.block_menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -2px;
  -moz-margin-top: -2px;
  -webkit-margin-top: -2px;
  -ms-margin-top: -2px;
  tabindex: -1;
}


/* Начало описания верхнего меню сайта. */

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 973px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  background: #51284f;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav ul li a {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: Pompadur;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

.nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
}

.nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 6px 0px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  color: #000;
}

.pod_nav1 {
  background: #red;
  width: 149px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}

.pod_nav2 {
  background: #red;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
}

.pod_nav3 {
  background: #red;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
}

.pod_nav4 {
  background: #red;
  width: 149px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  float: left;
}


/*Конец описания верхнего меню*/


/*Начало описания языковой панели*/

#languages_menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #51284f;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  float: right;
}

#languages_menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#languages_menu li {
  float: left;
}

#languages_menu li a {
  padding: 4px 0px;
  margin: 0px 7.3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#languages_menu li a:hover {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}


/*Конец описания языковой панели*/

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

.logo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo img {
  border: none;
}


/*Начало описания центрального меню*/

#middle_menu {
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  float: left;
}

#middle_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#middle_menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

#middle_menu li a {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Pompadur;
  display: block;
}

#middle_menu li a:hover {
  background: #444444;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Конец описания центрального меню*/

.wrapper_content {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1100px;
  /* border:1px solid #000; */
  float: left;
}

.wrapper_new {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.news_table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
}

.news_table h3 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}


/*----------------------Для пунктов меню и тегов----------------*/

.content {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

.one_new {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 350px;
  float: left;
}

.one_new h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.one_new p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #717171;
}

.one_new a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.one_new a:hover>h4 {
  color: #444;
}

.one_new a:hover>p {
  color: #000;
}

.right_div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 230px;
  height: 400px;
}

.cloud_tegs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 226px;
  border: 2px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.zaglav p {
  margin: 3px 3px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  background: #51284f;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tegs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.tegs img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 34px;
}

.tegs a {
  margin: 3px 4px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: c1c1c1;
  float: left;
}

.tegs a:hover {
  margin: 3px 4px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #444444;
}

.social_networks {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 226px;
  height: 86px;
  border: 2px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.social_networks p {
  margin: 3px 3px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  background: #51284f;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/*---------------------------Меню соц. сетей -----------------------*/

.social_networks ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.social_networks li {
  float: left;
}

.social_networks li a {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  margin: 3px 5px;
  display: block;
}

.social_networks li a:hover {
  padding: 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/*-----------------------------Для IE(Бордюр у изображений)-----------*/

.social_networks img {
  border: none;
}


/*-----------------------------Описание футера------------------------*/

.footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  background: #51284f;
  float: left;
}

.footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Arial";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Имя сайта</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">О ПРОЕКТЕ</a></li>
          <li class="uslugi"><a href="#">УСЛУГИ</a>
            <div class="block_menu">
              <ul class="pod_nav1">
                <li><a href="#">SEO Pakalpojumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Izpēte un audits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mājas lapas optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ārējā optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SEO Speciālisti</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="pod_nav2">
                <li><a href="#">SEO Pakalpojumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Izpēte un audits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mājas lapas optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ārējā optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SEO Speciālisti</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="pod_nav3">
                <li><a href="#">SEO Pakalpojumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Izpēte un audits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mājas lapas optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ārējā optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SEO Speciālisti</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="pod_nav4">
                <li><a href="#">SEO Pakalpojumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Izpēte un audits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mājas lapas optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ārējā optimizācija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SEO Speciālisti</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">НАПРАВЛЕНИЯ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ГОВЫЕ РЕШЕНИЯ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ПОРТФОЛИО И КЕЙСЫ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ЦЕНЫ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">КОМАНДА</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">КЛИЕНТЫ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ДРУЗЬЯ И ПАРТНЁРЫ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="languages_menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="indexEN.html">EN</a></li>
          <li><a href="indexLV.html">LV</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">RU</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Логотип"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle_menu">
      <ul="structures_menu">
        <li><a href="#">IT&DIGITAL</a>
          <!-- <ul>
     <li><a href="#">DIGITAL</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PROGRAMMING</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SMM</a></li>
    </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HORECA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ESTATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ART</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PERSONALITY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper_content">
      <div class="right_div">
        <div class="cloud_tegs">
          <div class="zaglav">
            <p>ОБЛАКО ТЕГОВ</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tegs">
            <a href="#">
              <ТЕКСТ ТЕГА>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <ТЕКСТ ТЕГА>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <ТЕКСТ ТЕГА>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <ТЕКСТ ТЕГА>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <ТЕКСТ ТЕГА>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social_networks">
          <p>МЫ В СОЦ. СЕТЯХ</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/VK_icon.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/YouTube_icon.png" /></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper_news">
        <div class="news_table">
          <h3>Обобщающий текст</h3>
          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_1.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>

          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_2.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>

          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_3.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>
          <!-- Новостей можно добавить больше простым копированим. Новости пойдут в 2 ряда -->
        </div>
        <div class="news_table">
          <h3>Обобщающий текст 2</h3>
          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_1.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>

          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_2.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>

          <div class="one_new">
            <img src="images/foto_news_3.png">
            <a href="#">
              <h4>Заголовок новости</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Какой то поясняющий текст к новости. Возможно дата и автор новсти. Текст описания не может привысить общую высоту блока: 350px</p>
          </div>
          <!-- Новостей можно добавить больше простым копированим. Новости пойдут в 2 ряда -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>SOFITEL&copy; Все права защищены. 2014г.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

I tried this: 
a)

```
window.addEventListener ("mouseup", function(event) {
var box = document.getElementByClassName ("uslugi");
if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
 box.style.display = "none";
}
});
```

b)

```
 $(".uslugi").click(function () {
 $(this).children().children().toggle();
 });
 $(".uslugi").click(function(){ 
  $(this).fadeIn(300,function(){$(this).focus();});
 });
 $(".uslugi").on('blur',function(){
$(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Comment: Typo: `mousup` should be `mouseup`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. :) But still did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to do it this way:

```
$(".uslugi>a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().children().toggle();
    $(this).focus();
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).siblings().children().hide();
});
```

Clicking outside the link will trigger `blur` event. [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEYgdE). Please note, had to `focus` anchor, because webkit browsers and IE do not focus it.

Comment: In codepen you don't need an account. You can edit the code as you like without login.

Comment: I edit the code and nothing happens, cant share. I updated the code in answer - use only that for JS.

Comment: Press Save or Fork and then Save. Then paste the link here. That's how it's done. :)

Comment: The action toggles only when clicked on the li item "uslugi".

Comment: That was the question. You can apply same to all menu items, just use another selector, for example `#header > nav > ul > li > a`.

Comment: How can I make the block_menu close when clicking outside? - This was the question. Excuse me if you did not understand it completely. I'll update in that case.

Comment: I see, was testing in Firefox and works fine. Webkit and IE do not trigger blur when clicking outside.

Comment: Oh. Hmm... and If I'm not mistaken, there is not a way to fix an issue with browsers in js, is there?

Comment: Works. Thank you! The focus outline is not a prob. Just put outline: none; in CSS :)

Comment: Oops, no it closes even when clicking inside. :/ oh my dayz

Comment: Clicking inside link would open new page, why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

Add event handler to the html element (applies to all children elements) HTML:

```
<html onclick="hidePopupMenus(event);">
```

Make the html element take up the whole page. CSS:

```
html
   {
    height:100%;
   }
```

Obviously you have a button or something that opens up the dialogue (if that isn't your case just make a small change to my script). When the function is fired it will make sure the `event.target.id` is not equal to the button that opens up the dialogue. If it isn't it continues with hiding whatever you're wanting to hide. ***If you don't have a button opening up this element just get rid of the `if` statement.*** javascript:

```
function hidePopupMenus(event)
{
    if(event.target.id != 'whateverOpensMyPopup')
    {
        document.getElementById('popUpThingy').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Did not work. A demo would be the best way to test it out.)

Answer (score 0):

The basics of toggling with a dropdown:

1) Use CSS to show and hide your dropdown based on a class being present

```
.uslugi .block_menu {
  display: none;
}

.uslugi.open .block_menu {
  display: block;
}
```

2) When the user clicks anywhere in the body, close all drop-downs

```
$(body).on("click", function() {
  $(".uslugi").removeClass("open");
});
```

3) Stop that event from firing when you click on a toggler, or within the dropdown itself:

```
$(".uslugi").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

4) Set an event on the toggler to toggle the class:

```
// You should set a class to fix this poor selector
$(".uslugi").children("a").on("click", function() {
  $(".uslugi").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: Could you explain how should I adapt it to my code? New to js and the way I put it in does not function. UPDATE: Didn't see your update. I'll try now.

Comment: I've now updated it to be more relevant to your code. Let me know if anything specific is confusing for you.

Comment: Well, I didn't manage, unfortunately. If it's ok with you, could you please show a demo within my code? I would be very grateful. Cause  learning html and css is ok but JS frustrates me for now.)